# Understanding (multiple) fetch operations in a hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to rewrite my old class-based react components using hooks, and I'm running into a problem with a component that makes two fetch calls instead of one (I suspect this maybe the issue). The states are not updating and I was hoping to better understand why. Here is what the code looks like:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
   isLoaded: false,
   isLoaded2: false,
   response1: null,
   response2: null,
   error: null
});

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("some api", { method: "GET" })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      res => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          isLoaded: true,
          response1: res
        });
      },
      error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  fetch("another api", {
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      res => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          response2: res,
          isLoaded2: true
        });
      },
      error => {
        setState({
          ...state,
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
}, []);
```

The states aren't updating and I checked to make sure the API responses are all ok. This structure worked using `ComponentDidMount()` so I'm wondering why it isn't working in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating state in functional components is still asynchronous, try using the [functional update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) syntax to "queue" up the updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("some api", { method: "GET" })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      res => {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          isLoaded: true,
          response1: res
        }));
      },
      error => {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          isLoaded: false,
          error: error
        }));
      }
    );
  fetch("another api", {
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      res => {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          response2: res,
          isLoaded2: true
        }));
      },
      error => {
        setState(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          error: error
        }));
      }
    );
}, []);
```

What is happening is even though there are several set states occurring, when processed they all reference the same state value from the previous render cycle.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const plus3Update = () => {
  setCount(count + 1); // count === 0
  setCount(count + 1); // count === 0
  setCount(count + 1); // count === 0
  // count === 1 now
};

const plus3FunctionalUpdate = () => {
  // using a different name to not be confused with state value
  setCount(c => c + 1); // count === 0, then 1
  setCount(c => c + 1); // count === 1, then 2
  setCount(c => c + 1); // count === 2, then 3
  // count === 3
};
```

demo showing both update and functional update state update methods.

[image: Edit infallible-pond-qkdhs]